# How to get all the quoted strings in a file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to extract all the strings surrounded with single quotes in a file. For instance, if a file contains the following line:

```
"Julius" was not "Ceaser"
```

It should output

```
Julius 
Ceaser
```

I want to do it using bash (Sed/Awk). Using Awk I can extract one occurrence but how do I get all the strings?

Comment: there is an important difference between single quotes and double quotes.  What you posted is double quotes.

Answer (score 7):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS='"' '!(NR%2)' file

Julius
Ceaser
```

using this contents

```
$ cat file
```

> I need to extract all the strings surrounded with single quotes in a file. For instance, if a file contains the following line: "Julius"
>   was not "Ceaser" It should output Julius Ceaser

assumes there are no escaped quotes.

Comment: If a single line has multiple quoted strings, this solution prints them on different lines.  Not sure if OP wanted that.

Comment: Perhaps, but in the question that's how the output is shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Eo '"[a-zA-Z]+"' file
```

would print the matching strings on separate lines, even if they were on the same line in the original file.  If you want to fold the matches, you could do this:

```
grep -nEo '"[a-zA-Z]+"' file | awk -F: '
BEGIN { p=1 }
      {
         gsub("\"", "", $2)
         n=$1;
         if (p != n) {
           print s; s = $2; p=n
         } else {
           if(s) { s = s" "$2 } else { s=$2 }
         }
      }
END   {
         print s
      }'
```

- `grep -nEo` extracts only the matched parts, with the line number prefixed
- awk parses grep's output and produces the desired result

Comment: you may want to trim the quotation marks.  Also perhaps `"[^"]+"` is more inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the double quoted string in the same lines, then try this Perl one-liner

```
perl -ne ' while(/("\S+")/g) { print "$1 " } print "\n" '
```

with given inputs

```
$ cat  doubleq.txt
"Julius" was not "Ceaser"
"request" map url
"Ceaser"


$ perl -ne ' while(/("\S+")/g) { print "$1 " } print "\n" ' doubleq.txt
"Julius" "Ceaser"
"request"
"Ceaser"

$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind your output including the quotes, a simple `grep -o` might work:

```
$ egrep -o '"[[:alnum:]]+"'  <<<'"Julius" was not "Ceaser"'
"Julius"
"Ceaser"
```

And it you want no quotes, `grep -P` (mostly on Linux) or `pcregrep` (FreeBSD, macOS and other BSDs) might work, using a negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
$ pcregrep -o '(?<=")[[:alnum:]]+(?=")'  <<<'"Julius" was not "Ceaser"'
Julius 
Ceaser
```